# Is it good practice to get EF Database name via static variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building a application which will be connected to different database of the same schema based on the Database choose by the user at the time of log in. All the subsequent queries will be made by EntityFramework using the database selected. at the moment I am storing this Database Name in a static variable. Is it the right way to do it?

Here is how I did it.

I have created a static variable in My Context and when I am creating a new instance of the context inside the constructor it calls the Static variable.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public static string LoggedDatabase { get; set; }

    static MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }

    public MyContext()
        : base(GetConnectionString())
    {
    }

    private static string GetConnectionString()
    {
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LoggedDatabase))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("", "Database is not specified");
        var connBuilder =
            new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString)
            {
                InitialCatalog = LoggedDatabase
            };
        return connBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: `static` is definetly not the way to go. Not sure what exactly you want to get as behavour but it seems like `readonly` is closer to what will match your needs.

Comment: I am building a web based solution for a legacy application. There are 9 Databases for each division which shares the same schema. User will choose the database from the log in screen and as per the selection the connection string will be dynamically created. now the issue is the context is shared in both WPF and Asp.net clients. so I need a solution which will solve both the requirements. I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static variable will be shared among all the sessions in other word when the user login all other users will be using the database that the last user used, so you need to store the value somewhere else in the Session for example.

'public static string LoggedDatabase { get; set; }
You can change the getter and the setter to get and set the value from the session object'

Comment: I understand your point. But the issue is MyDbContext is in a different Project and I am using it for WPF Client as well. And if I modify the property as you suggested it will create coupling with Asp.net. Can you suggest something on this regard please?

Comment: Can you add another constructor for MyContext class  public MyContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString) that will not break your code in the WPF project or you> if so can you also create a new class for example class DynamicContext : MyContext and use it your WEB app code and call the base(connectionString) for the current user

Comment: Thats a Nice suggession. Thanks Aladin Hdabe. I will have a look at it. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can create your variable `LoggedDatabase` and method `GetConnectionString` with ThreadStatic attribute, to make each it unique for each thread. But it is a wrong way.

There are several solutions for it.

1. Store it in session.
2. Store it in db
3. Store it in global static Dictionary(UserId,LoggedDatabase)
4. Store it in external xml file.

and so on